How can I set the display attribute back to what it was prior to hiding an element?
In some JavaScript, I hide an element by doing this:
element.style.display = 'none';

When I want to display it again, I could do that same thing and set it to block. However, I won't know what it was before I changed it. It could have been inline-block for all I know.
This means that I can't really use this method, unless I wanted to store the prior value first. (Something I could conceivably do...)
I thought about moving to some hidden area (like a template tag or something), but then I'd have to have some way of remembering exactly where it came from.
Is there another way to remove an element from the layout (so display, not visibility), without changing the display style property, so that I don't have to worry about getting it back to what it was?

display: initial?? - MDN Ref

This question is similar to: Reset CSS display property to default value. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@HereticMonkey The ambiguity is what "default value" means. I think in the question to linked to, the phrase refers to the browser default. In my usage, it refers to what the HTML specified just before it was hidden. Not quite the same thing, I don't think.

The answers you get will be the same; Use an empty string or unset. Or copy the current value into a variable before setting it.

Don't set the inline style at all. Add a CSS class to hide the element and then just remove that class to restore it.

You can store the state it was before setting it to none.


function hide(element) {
  element.setAttribute("data-old-display", element.style.display);
  element.style.display = 'none';
}

function restore(element) {
  element.style.display = element.getAttribute("data-old-display");
}
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
<button onclick="hide(document.querySelector('.square'))">hide</button>
<button onclick="restore(document.querySelector('.square'))">restore</button>
<div class="square">
</div>




A simpler way for setting and reading custom data attributes is to use the dataset property.

@it-goldman Yes, this was my inclination as well. Thanks for validating it.

@Sean That is a great tip that I did not know. Thank you.

Personally I prefer to use data-something explicit, it's more verbose and easier to search & replace.

Use a class and toggle it.
Here I just add a selector to a button and then toggle a hidden class.
NOTE: I put the hidden CSS after the "normal" CSS but you could add specificity also if needed/desired here instead.
I used a grid display just to show it could be anything.


const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-it');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const toggleTarget = this.dataset.target;
  document.querySelector(toggleTarget).classList.toggle('hidden');
});
.hide-show-me {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50vh;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<button type="button" class="toggle-it" data-target=".hide-show-me">toggle it</button>
<div class="hide-show-me">text to toggle with button</div>



Fix up the style first


// Create a new <style> element
const style = document.createElement("style");

// Add CSS rules to the style element
style.textContent = `
.hide-show-me {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50vh;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
`;

// Append the style element to the <head> of the document
document.head.appendChild(style);
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-it');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const toggleTarget = this.dataset.target;
  document.querySelector(toggleTarget).classList.toggle('hidden');
});
<button type="button" class="toggle-it" data-target=".hide-show-me">toggle it</button>
<div class="hide-show-me">text to toggle with button</div>




I really do like this, but sadly I won't have access to the CSS to add the class rule.

you COULD append a <style> to the document using JavaScript at the start then just use it also.

I added that style append as a second example :)

Set an empty string to the display property


function hide() { 
  document.querySelector(".box").style.display="none"
}
function show() { 
  document.querySelector(".box").style.display=""
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline grid;
  place-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button {
  font-size: 25px;
}
<button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
<br>
<div class="box">text</div>




But what if it did have a display property set? Like, it was set to inline-block or something in the HTML?

@Deane if the display is set inline in the HTML then you only solution is to store that value before overriding it.
